# How to retrieve all static texts from resource in a mvc website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, multilingual

I want to build a multi language website. I found some resource about that but I don't know how I can retrieve texts from resource file and put it on a HTML tag.
for example I have a **h1** tag and I want to get it's text from resource file and change this text according to selected language.

I mean I don't know about how to use localization in views.

thanks for help

Comment: Have you created resx files?

Comment: @CodeNotFount thanks for replay...yes i create resx file but i don't know how i can use this resource on a view (cshtml)

Answer (score 0):

As i do not have reputation to sent a comment yet. Here is a link on how this is done from Microsoft for ASP.NET Core MVC.
[Globalization and localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization)
For ASP.NET MVC 5 you can check a helpful tutorial from [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/778040/Beginners-Tutorial-on-Globalization-and-Localizati)

Comment: thanks but this code project link is about models and html helpers but i want to use localization for plain html...for example i have a h1 element or a p element and i want to set it's inner text from resource file

Comment: Read more carefully through the tutorials. They demonstrate this too. If you add a custom namespace to the resource file you will be able to reference​ it as if it was a class with static fields

Answer (score 0):

You can read this article about [ASP.NET Core MVC Localization by URL](https://irensaltali.com/en/asp-net-core-mvc-localization-by-url-routedatarequestcultureprovider/).

And also there is GitHub [repo](https://github.com/irensaltali/AspNetCoreMVCLocalizationByURL) of implementation of that article. Project is built on ASP.NET Core 2.0.